# Log users on official app using WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I have built a WordPress website and I am developping an app that goes with it.

The problem is, how do I allow wp users to log in using the REST API of WP ? I've can not retrieve passwords using this API, and I can send a password check to verify the one entered on the app.

I suppose their is some sort of procedure to keep the password secure but I can't seem to find out which one.

I plan on putting the whole site on SSL, so passing password in request should be quite safe, shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution so far : Create a new REST route that allow to check user/password combination when passed through URL.

This needs a SSL safety on the route.